# Create infinite number of EditText on Clicking the button in custom dialog

Tags: android

I have to create a edit text one by one below inside custom dialog while clicking the button.

So far I have tried and created one edit text on clicking the button in custom dialog.

**MainActivity.java:**

Below I am shown the code what I had tried so far:

Edited:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    EditText et;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                //setting custom layout to dialog
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("Add List");


                //adding button click event
                Button createEditText = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);

                createEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    //  dialog.dismiss();


                         et= new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                         params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                        dialog.addContentView(et,params);
                       ((LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.container)).addView(et);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }


        });
    }

}
```

**custom_dialog_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know how to create infinite number of edittext one by one below.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done it before is to have some containing layout (linearlayout, usually) and add my views to that container. Rough code:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
```

and in your onclick listener

```
EditText edit = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
container.addView(edit);
```

**Edit**

Okay, after managing to absolutely miss the point of your question in my initial post, I went and checked out what was going on. What's happening (I think) is that it IS actually adding more edittexts, but they're all on top of each other so it looks like that it's not. So here's what you have to do, which plays into what I wrote above:

In your custom dialog view, add a linearlayout container

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container"></LinearLayout>
```

and in your onclick, you add your edit texts to the linearlayout, NOT the dialog view

```
                    et= new EditText(TestActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    ((LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.container)).addView(et);
```

and that should work.

Comment: Remove `dialog.addContentView(et,params);`

Comment: I removed that.But I am getting `container cannot be resolved to a type` at this line ` ((LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.container)).addView(et);`

Comment: Hmm. Is it intentional that you called your view `custom_dialog_view.xml:` but it's listed as `custom_dialog_layout.xml` in your code?

Comment: extremely sorry that is custom_dialog_layout.xml only.typo error

Comment: Hmm. I just plugged your code into my test activity and it works perfectly. Check to see if the LinearLayout import still exists in the class header.